# Loading CSV data using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

i am unable load csv using the below pandas commnads.

```
f1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sana.mohan.reddy\Desktop\Python_Practice\Test1.CSV', skiprows=[0,1,2], skip_footer=[0], sep = ',')
```

I have to skip first 3 rows and last row.

**Below is the sample data.**

Contacts - Total Opens by Campaign

```
Email Open Date/Time,"Total Opens"
3/25/2016 6:00:35 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:35 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:51 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:52 AM,"1"
Total,"796"
```

could you please correct me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with other parameters (`sep = ','` is omited, because `,` is default value of `sep`):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''Email Open Date/Time,"Total Opens"
3/25/2016 6:00:35 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:35 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:51 AM,"1"
3/25/2016 6:00:52 AM,"1"
Total,"796"'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                 skipfooter=1, #skip last row
                 engine='python', #remove warning
                 skiprows=[0,1,2], #remove first 3 rows
                 header=None) #no header, set default 0,1,... 
print (df)

                      0  1
0  3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM  1
1  3/25/2016 6:00:46 AM  1
2  3/25/2016 6:00:51 AM  1
3  3/25/2016 6:00:52 AM  1
```

EDIT by real data:

There was main problem with encoding - I have to set `utf-16`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Test 1.csv',
                 skipfooter=1, #skip last row
                 engine='python', #remove warning
                 skiprows=[0,1], #remove first 2 rows
                 encoding='utf-16', #set encoding
                 parse_dates=[0]) #convert first column to datetime 
print (df)

    Email Open Date/Time  Total Opens
0    2016-03-25 06:00:35            1
1    2016-03-25 06:00:35            1
2    2016-03-25 06:00:46            1
3    2016-03-25 06:00:46            1
4    2016-03-25 06:00:51            1
5    2016-03-25 06:00:52            1
6    2016-03-25 06:00:57            1
7    2016-03-25 06:00:58            1
8    2016-03-25 06:01:03            1
9    2016-03-25 06:01:20            1
10   2016-03-25 06:01:20            1
11   2016-03-25 06:01:25            1
```

Comment: Error: line contains NULL byte i am getting this error any help on this in my csv file the first row is string the second row is blank the third row is string and from fourth row i have the actual data and the last row i am skipping

Comment: Is possible share your file?

Comment: how to share the file i dont see any attachment link or option

Comment: You have to upload file to some share server, e.g. https://www.wetransfer.com/ and then share link.

Comment: your email id please i can transfer the file

Comment: use jezrael@mailinator.com

Comment: i have sent the attachment

Comment: Hmmm, but my answer is not accepted, something wrong?

Comment: write_excel = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
f4.to_frame().to_excel(write_excel, sheet_name='Report') i am exporting the data that has been grouped to excel its creating a file but its not having data and i want the file to be exported to the path i need but this one is getting exported to default path

Comment: Hmmm, for me works `df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Report')`

Comment: sorry it worked for me too..there was an issue but if i want to give it to a specific location how should i do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your `read_csv` to:

```
f1 = pd.read_csv('yourFile.csv', skiprows=3, skip_footer=1, sep = ',')
```

since `skip_footer` requires an integer value (the number of lines to skip at the bottom of the file) see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: f1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sana.mohan.reddy\Desktop\Python_Practice\Test 1.csv', skiprows=3, skipfooter=1, sep = ',', engine='python') it is throwing an error like 'Line contains NULL byte' how to deal with this

Comment: Error: line contains NULL byte i am getting this error any help on this in my csv file the first row is string the second row is blank the third row is string and from fourth row i have the actual data and the last row i am skipping